# Hide/Show div based on datePicker & current date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, date, datepicker

I'd like to change text of a div based on the date in the date picker with the following scenarios

- if the datePicker date is today, I want msg1,
- elseif datePicker date is tomorrow and current time is >= 3pm, I want msg2,
- elseif datepicker date is tomorrow, I want msg3,
- elseif datePicker date is +2days of current date, I want msg4,
- else, no msg.

DatePicker field...

```
<input type="text" name="orderTime" class="" id="orderTime" value="" autocomplete="off" /><br><br>
<script type="text/javascript">         
        jQuery("#orderTime").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true, 
            changeYear: false, 
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', 
            firstDay: 1, 
            duration: 'fast', 
            maxDate: '+2m', 
            minDate: '-0d', 
            numberOfMonths: 1
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Other than instantiating a datepicker, what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Use **OnSelect** option of DatePicker

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">            
    jQuery("#orderTime").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true, 
        changeYear: false, 
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', 
        firstDay: 1, 
        duration: 'fast', 
        maxDate: '+2m', 
        minDate: '-0d', 
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function (selectDate){
          // write your logic here  
          if(today) // today logic
            alert('today')
          else if(tomorrow) // tomorrow logic
            alert('tomorrow') 
        }
    });
</script>
```